# Should I rollback a minor edit that a >2k rep user has made?

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

If a user with sufficient privileges to edit **without approval** edits a post, but the edit *only changes word choice*, how should I feel about rolling back?

The only reason I hesitate is because such an edit hasn't caused *harm* to the post, but **if the edit was in the review queue, I'd reject it** as too minor.

Comment: Nah, rollback is for more extreme cases, like vandalism. A good portion of edits get rejected because they were **too minor**, not **causing harm**. (*We don't have enough bamwar spammers yet*)

Comment: I'm so tempted to roll back your edit @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ

Comment: It does however, only really change word choice. The meaning hasn't changed.

Comment: Don't rollback any time you see a borderline edit. The main reason that button exists is to counter vandalism. If an edit adds the smallest value, you should keep it IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say **no**.  Rollbacks should only be done if the edit was harmful.

I say this because once an edit has been saved, *it's saved*. There's no point adding *another* revision just to change a word (you're basically doing the same thing again!). Anyway, this is one of the 'benefits' of having >2k -- to edit even small posts! :P

But if you see a specific user continually editing minor things in *old* posts (unnecessarily bumping them), then I'd flag one of these edits and detail this undesirable behavior. Or talk to them in chat.

Answer (score 5):

If the edit does not make any difference whatsoever (in your opinion), *so will rolling it back.* Rolling back will thus be as bad an edit as the original edit was. It will needlessly bump the post, send an alert to the author, etc.